# Quick Question: Whats wrong with this pre-processor directive in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Whats wrong with these pre-processor directive in C#

```
#define OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "E:\asdf\sdfg\jhkl\"
```

I also tried giving:

```
#define OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "E:\\asdf\\sdfg\\jhkl\\"
```

for both I get error:

> Error 1   Single-line comment or
>   end-of-line expected

Answer (score 4):

You cannot give that symbol (OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) a value, the symbol can only be "defined" or "undefined" so you can use it in a `#if OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` ... `#endif`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You define a *symbol*. You can't assign a value to it.

Symbols are not variables. See more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

The usage could be:

```
 #ifdef OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
   someVariable = "E:\\asdf\\sdfg\\jhkl\\"
 #endif
```

Comment: then what is `#define PI 3.1428`

Comment: @pecker - that would be C++. In C# we have `Math.PI`, and quite happy with it.

Comment: It's C or C++, not C#.  And it's also approximately 0.0012 greater than pi. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Oded and Hans' answers, I'd recommend simply making it a constant rather than trying to use the pre-processor. If it's used by multiple classes, define it in a common class.