# C# Preprocessor Directives in interpolated verbatim string literal

Tags: c#, string, compilation, conditional-compilation, preprocessor-directive

I have a problem during build. Unity game engine has platform-dependent compilation. `#if UNITY_EDITOR ... #endif`.

During build the following string is valid and everything builds fine.

```cs
string format = $@"/* Created by ... */

using ...;

using ...;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;

public partial class ...
{{{{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Texture2D s_scriptIcon = (EditorGUIUtility.IconContent(""cs Script Icon"").image as Texture2D);{{0}}
}}}}
#endif
";
```

But this next instance doesn't. And it throws an exception - `"error CS1025: Single-line comment or end-of-line expected"`. This left me with conclusion that even though `#if`, `#endif` are in string, they are still being considered as `Preprocessor Directives` by compiler. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour and make sure that they are strings and to make compiler ignore them?

```cs
string format = $@"/* Created by ... */

using ...;

using ...;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;

public partial class ...
{{{{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Texture2D s_scriptIcon = (EditorGUIUtility.IconContent(""cs Script Icon"").image as Texture2D);{{0}}
}}}}
#endif"; // Notice this line. This is where the error happens as well.
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? [It compiles fine for me.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rNIvJi)

Comment: @Sweeper I assume it may compile fine because it doesn't care about `#if UNITY_EDITOR`. It compiles fine when I am in `Unity Editor`, but as soon as I try to make a build of a game - it throws this error. I have found this error is a common thing, and usually happens when there is something after, for example, `#if ... ` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Well, Dot Net Fiddle certainly is not the Unity Editor. I feel like this is a Unity quirk/bug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756801/quick-question-whats-wrong-with-this-pre-processor-directive-in-c-sharp - this is relevant, that is why I thought it was a language specific problem, not a Unity one.